# What does the author mean by "to deposit data"?

Tags: meaning, usage

> Researchers depositing data from their project that were obtained from another source should identify the original source as well as the researcher's right to distribute the data.

I have often seen the verb *deposit* with money referring to "to put money into a bank account" and several other similar meanings. But, I am wondering what the author means in the above-mentioned paragraph by *depositing data*.

Comment: I'd say it means the same. A code or research database is a 'repository'. It wouldn't be too far a stretch to imagine you can deposit to a repository - you could reposit, but that implies 'put back' rather than just 'put'.

Comment: @JasonStack When you came across the word in the passage, did you look it up- for example on Google "define [word]"? This isn't a rhetorical question.

Comment: @Gary Having looked at googles define word, it doesn't actually help in this instance, as depositing data is quite a fringe case for the word.

Comment: @mjbk88 I disagree. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original passage is from a data sharing and archiving protocol guide from the Inter-University Consortium for Political and Social Research in the Netherlands.

> "Some projects may combine data from one or more secondary sources. Derived
>   datasets created by collating materials from existing sources and presenting them
>   in a new way could constitute a new dataset. A project may also be considered
>   to be producing a new dataset if it combines (a) primary and secondary data; (b) secondary data with newly created variables; or (c) secondary data based on data
>   that are not yet publicly available. If the project meets any of the above conditions
>   and would be useful to other researchers in supporting new research, reproducing
>   original findings, or testing new hypotheses, then archiving the dataset should
>   be considered. **Researchers depositing data from their project that were obtained
>   from another source should identify the original source as well as the researcher’s
>   right to distribute the data.**"

The word deposit is used as a verb. The first definition of that form means to "put", specifically "in a specific place". Therefore:

> "Researchers [***putting***] data from their project [*into a new project*] that were obtained from another source should identify the original source as well as the researcher's right to distribute the data."

Reading the guide, it is obvious that it was not written by native-English speakers. Nevertheless, the word deposit was used appropriately and consistent with one of its dictionary definition.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To deposit data would mean the placement of said data to somewhere, whether it is a person, institution or database. In this instance, the word "depositing" can be substituted with "submitting" to aid in the understanding of the meaning.